# Последовательные запросы к mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.30 WHERE price <=10";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.25 WHERE price FROM 11 TO 30";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.22 WHERE price FROM 31 TO 50";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.20 WHERE price FROM 51 TO 70";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.18 WHERE price FROM 71 TO 80";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.15 WHERE price FROM 81 TO 95";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.12 WHERE price FROM 96 TO 180";
$sql = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.10 WHERE price >=181";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Выполняет только последнюю наценку.
Как перестроить, чтобы наценялось в зависимости от цены?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn)
{
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sqls = array(
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.30 WHERE price <=10",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.25 WHERE price FROM 11 TO 30",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.22 WHERE price FROM 31 TO 50",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.20 WHERE price FROM 51 TO 70",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.18 WHERE price FROM 71 TO 80",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.15 WHERE price FROM 81 TO 95",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.12 WHERE price FROM 96 TO 180",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.10 WHERE price >=181");

foreach($sqls as $sql)
{
  if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
  {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Error updating record: ".mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Поспешил с ответом. В данном случае скрипт наценяет оду позицию несколько раз. То есть если была цена 60,36, наценяет 20% до 72,432, потом еще раз наценяет 18% до 85,46976 и так далее, пока число попадает в запросы

Comment: это уже другой вопрос :) первый был про последовательные запросы

Comment: Затупил, признаю. Получается мне нужно все выполнить одним запросом?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте лучше так:

```
$sql = array();
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.30 WHERE price <=10";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.25 WHERE price FROM 11 TO 30";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.22 WHERE price FROM 31 TO 50";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.20 WHERE price FROM 51 TO 70";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.18 WHERE price FROM 71 TO 80";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.15 WHERE price FROM 81 TO 95";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.12 WHERE price FROM 96 TO 180";
$sql[] = "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.10 WHERE price >=181";

if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, implode(";", $sql))) {
    echo "Records updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating records: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Отлично. Спасибо

Подошёл первый вариант, только забыл указать, что использую mariadb, поэтому вот ответ:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sqls = array(
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.30 WHERE price <=10",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.25 WHERE price >=11 and price <=30",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.22 WHERE price >=31 and price <=50",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.20 WHERE price >=51 and price <=70",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.18 WHERE price >=71 and price <=80",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.15 WHERE price >=81 and price <= 95",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.12 WHERE price >=96 and price <= 180",
  "UPDATE elitprice SET price=price*1.10 WHERE price >=181");

foreach($sqls as $sql)
{
  if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
  {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Error updating record: ".mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, если у вас в базе цены могут быть дробными, то вы пропускаете некоторые строки на границах ваших условий. Например интервал цен от 30.01 до 30.99 не попадает ни под одно условие. и так собственно по каждому интервалу

Comment: поэтому колонке price присвоил тип decimal(19,0)